# What kind of a sensor is this to detect metal rotating?

Tags: sensor, metal

I looking for this fat component (brown ) on a PCB:

[image]

This component using in a textile mill. There is a small metal (buckle) rotating around a disk and this sensor detects whether this small piece of metal is rotating or stopped.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The component looks like an inductor. In this application is may be being used as a reluctor in that a small DC current is passed through the inductor creating a magnetic field. The rotating metal part affects this field and imparts an AC pulse. Something like a capacitor and comparator is used to detect this and provide a clean pulse.

Comment: Or, if the RPM is extremely low, the inductor may act as a metal-detector, but driven by high-freq AC.  Or, the small rotating metal part may actually be a strong magnet.